# Is it possible to get the createTextNode method to render html tags?

Tags: javascript

The following code prints

**This should print**(b)This should print(/b)**This should print**

```
<script>
function produceMessage(){
    var msg= '<b>This should print</b>';
    return msg;
}

</script>

<span id="mySpan"></span>

<script>

    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(produceMessage()));
    document.write(produceMessage());
    document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML=produceMessage();
</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, a text node will not print any HTML. Instead, create an element, or use a document fragment to insert HTML in that way.

```
function boldHTML() {
  var element = document.createElement("b");
  element.innerHTML = "Bold text";
  return element;
}
document.body.appendChild(boldHTML());
```

will print **Bold text**.

Comment: Would it be bad practice to use encase javascript in inline elements? <span style="color:red"><script>document.body.appendChild(boldHTML());</script></span>

Comment: @user784637 although it is easier to hardcode tags like this, for better readability and maintenance, using document to create node is preferred. For code reuse and mutability, document node is recommended.