# How to adding special html chars without using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm working on a micro lib, [html.js](https://github.com/voldsoftware/html/), and basically it creates text nodes with `document.createTextNode` but when I want to create a text node with `a&nbsp;b` I get `a&amp;nbsp;b` so I'm wondering how to escape the `&` char, without using innerHTML ideally..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the the createTextNode method to render html tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965498/is-it-possible-to-get-the-the-createtextnode-method-to-render-html-tags)

Comment: @James, that question is about html tags, and I'm talking about special chars, also suggested solution there was using innerHTML which I cannot use (too many reasons).

Comment: Actually innerHTML can't be used, since it would destroy nodes already added to a parentNode.

Comment: Another reason I want to avoid using innerHTML is to prevent users from mangling an html string together and using that.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript supports the `\uXXXX` notation, so in the case of a non-breaking space, that would be `\u00A0`.

`document.createTextNode('a\u00A0b');`

That's as far as you can get. It's a text node, consisting only of text, and there's no difference between texts created from entity references or from normal characters.

If that's not what you want, you should take a second look at innerHtml. Can't you read it, modify it and put it back?

Comment: html.js adds listeners to html elements via addEventListener, and returns a reference to the HTMLElement so I can't have the node overwritten or wiped out using innerHTML.

Comment: This looks like a good way for users to avoid having to use html entities, but I'd like to have a solution for them if they do use it.

Comment: Nice, do have any good references for those kinds of notations?

Comment: maybe it's possible to do a character mapping?

Comment: You can do things like `replace('&nbsp;', ' ')` manually, but there is no built in routine that does all of them. You'll need an exteral library for that.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much functionality in js to encode/decode html entities. Seems like there some libraries out there, though, that can help you achieve this. Here is one I found on goodle.. haven't tried it, but you can check it out, or look for others.

http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

Comment: I hope you can find a better answer than using a library for this. I would be interested ;)