# DIV with <br> new line text

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, dom

in my project i have an xmlhttpresponse object with some node, and i need to print element of one (serps) in a div obj but formatted.
Node is like this:

[image]

now i have to create a div where store serps info like response.serps[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cb1I.png).headline+"
"+response.serps[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cb1I.png).url+"
"+response.serps[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRNnf.png).headline+"
"+response.serps[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRNnf.png).url ecc ecc and in my code i have tried like this:

```
//Data
    var divSerp3 = createElement('div', 'divSerp3', 'divSerp3css');
    if (typeof(response.serps) === 'undefined' || response.serps === null) {
        tse3 = document.createTextNode("NO DATA");
    } else {
              tse3 = document.createTextNode(response.serps[1].headline+"  <br>"+response.serps[1].url+"<br><br>"+response.serps[2].headline+"     <br>"+response.serps[2].url+"<br><br>"+response.serps[3].headline+"<br>"+response.serps[3].url+"<br><br>"+response.serps[4].headline+"<br>"+response.serps[4].url+"<br><br>"+response.serps[5].headline+"   <br>"+response.serps[5].url);
    }
 divSerp3.appendChild(tse3);
```

but the result is like:

[image]

How can i cycle my entire serps node and insert data in a formatted mode into my div??

Comment: you are creating a text node, so "<" and ">" replaced with &lt; and &gt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a text node, create an element and use innerHTML.

```
var divSerp3 = createElement('div', 'divSerp3', 'divSerp3css');
if (typeof(response.serps) === 'undefined' || response.serps === null) {
    tse3 = document.createTextNode("NO DATA");
} else {
    tse3 = document.createElement('span');
    tse3.innerHTML = response.serps[1].headline+"  <br>"+response.serps[1].url+"<br><br>"+response.serps[2].headline+"     <br>"+response.serps[2].url+"<br><br>"+response.serps[3].headline+"<br>"+response.serps[3].url+"<br><br>"+response.serps[4].headline+"<br>"+response.serps[4].url+"<br><br>"+response.serps[5].headline+"   <br>"+response.serps[5].url);
}
divSerp3.appendChild(tse3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Html won't be rendered correctly in a TextNode.. as the element's name says by itself, its content is basically textual.

I suggest you to append `<br>` separately and I would not use `createTextNode()`.. I'd append as many childs as you need using the appropriate html elements (like spans, paragraphs, etc..) and filling their content with `$.html('your content')` function if you are using jQuery library or `element.innerHtml` if you are working with pure javascript.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a `TextNode` which will take all of your `html` and parse it as text. You want to `document.createElement('br')` and append those instead of doing `+"<br><br>"`

Answer (score 1):

HTML won't render when inside a text node. See [Is it possible to get the the createTextNode method to render html tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965498/is-it-possible-to-get-the-the-createtextnode-method-to-render-html-tags)

You could create `<br>` elements and append them.

Or you could use newlines instead of `<br>` and use CSS [`white-space: pre-wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)